# Row count in Oracle import log differs from row count retrieved in sql developer and FME

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, fme

After importing a oracle dump, the log file tells me that 86643 rows were imported; however, when I use sql developer and FME to retrieve the tables row count, only 86,198 rows are shown. What would cause this inconsistency?

Comment: do you have any triggers? how about scheduled jobs? users on the system? these are all things that could be deleting records

Answer (score 0):

There could be tables imported in other schema. Run the below query to get more extensive list of tables in the database check if that matches your expected count.

```
Select * from all_tables;
```